# magento 2 compile error classloader

Tags: magento2, error, compile

I get this error when I do magento compile even have searched off the internet and it could be something with upgrade to php 8.1 or something not compatible with it, but just haven't found any solution yet.

`magento ClassLoader.php(433): Composer\Autoload\{closure}() #1 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()  #2 /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(134): class_exists()  #3 /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(117): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->includeClass()  #4 /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(87): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->extract()  #5 /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/RepositoryGenerator.php(61): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->getList()  #6 /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php(56): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\RepositoryGenerator->doOperation()  #7 /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php(216): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process()  #8 /vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute()  #9 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1011): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()  #10 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(272): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()  #11 /vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(116): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()  #12 /vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(148): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun()  #13 /bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() #14 {main}`

Comment: run "composer dump-autoload" command and then check resolve your error or not..